# how to implement json array nested in ui flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I parse json array nested object to `ListView` in UI using `Flutter`?

The API response is

```
{
  "responseCode": "0000",
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "date": "20200227",
  "time": "115221",
  "content": [
    {
      "postingDate": "20191203",
      "valueDate": "20191203",
      "inputDate": "20191203",
      "inputTime": "214808",
      "desc": "BUNGA JATUH TEMPO"
    },
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check out this example where I have parsed you JSON locally :

```
{
    "responseCode": "0000",
    "responseMessage": "Success",
    "date": "20200227",
    "time": "115221",
    "content": [
      {
        "postingDate": "20191203",
        "valueDate": "20191203",
        "inputDate": "20191203",
        "inputTime": "214808",
        "desc": "BUNGA JATUH TEMPO",
        "noReff": "B2100000000026",
        "amount": "+20712,33",
        "balance": "+6971357445,15"
      },
      {
        "postingDate": "20191203",
        "valueDate": "20191203",
        "inputDate": "20191203",
        "inputTime": "214809",
        "desc": "BUNGA JATUH TEMPO",
        "noReff": "B2100000000033",
        "amount": "+13808,22",
        "balance": "+6971371253,37"
      }
    ]
  }
```

below is the model class for the json that you provided.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final myModel = myModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

MyModel myModelFromJson(String str) => MyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String myModelToJson(MyModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MyModel {
    String responseCode;
    String responseMessage;
    String date;
    String time;
    List<Content> content;

    MyModel({
        this.responseCode,
        this.responseMessage,
        this.date,
        this.time,
        this.content,
    });

    factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyModel(
        responseCode: json["responseCode"],
        responseMessage: json["responseMessage"],
        date: json["date"],
        time: json["time"],
        content: List<Content>.from(json["content"].map((x) => Content.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "responseCode": responseCode,
        "responseMessage": responseMessage,
        "date": date,
        "time": time,
        "content": List<dynamic>.from(content.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Content {
    String postingDate;
    String valueDate;
    String inputDate;
    String inputTime;
    String desc;
    String noReff;
    String amount;
    String balance;

    Content({
        this.postingDate,
        this.valueDate,
        this.inputDate,
        this.inputTime,
        this.desc,
        this.noReff,
        this.amount,
        this.balance,
    });

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        postingDate: json["postingDate"],
        valueDate: json["valueDate"],
        inputDate: json["inputDate"],
        inputTime: json["inputTime"],
        desc: json["desc"],
        noReff: json["noReff"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        balance: json["balance"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "postingDate": postingDate,
        "valueDate": valueDate,
        "inputDate": inputDate,
        "inputTime": inputTime,
        "desc": desc,
        "noReff": noReff,
        "amount": amount,
        "balance": balance,
    };

// remove this method from the model
static Future<MyModel> getMutasiDetails(String accNumber, String startDate, String endDate) async {
  String apiURL = urlAPI";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
    var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
    };

  var params = Map<String, dynamic>();
  params['accNumber'] = accNumber;
  params['startDate'] = startDate;
  params['endDate'] = endDate;

  http.Response apiResult =
      await http.post(apiURL, body: params, headers: headers);
  if (apiResult.statusCode == 200) {
    return MyModel.fromJson(json.decode(apiResult.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('failed to load data');
  }
}
}
```

And below is the main file where the listview gets rendered:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyModel youModel = new MyModel();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMutasiDetails("0002100000291", "", "").then((value) {
      youModel = value;
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<MyModel> getMutasiDetails(
      String accNumber, String startDate, String endDate) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String apiURL = "urlAPI";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
    var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
    };

    var params = Map<String, dynamic>();
    params['accNumber'] = accNumber;
    params['startDate'] = startDate;
    params['endDate'] = endDate;

    http.Response apiResult =
        await http.post(apiURL, body: params, headers: headers);
    if (apiResult.statusCode == 200) {
      return myModelFromJson(apiResult.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('failed to load data');
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: youModel.content.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(youModel.content[i].amount),
                          Text(youModel.content[i].balance),
                          Text(youModel.content[i].inputDate),
                          Text(youModel.content[i].desc),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting. can you please elaborate it properly, I am not getting you English.

Comment: just check out the changes i have made in the code and let me know.

Comment: I am run Debugging this warning: StateError (Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".)

Comment: thats because you are incorrectly setting bodyFields

Comment: i was updated code in above, please advice. thanks.

Comment: just change this params instead of yours: var params = jsonEncode({'accNumber':accNumber,'startDate': startDate, 'endDate':startDate}); and then pass to the post api.

Comment: this error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#53efa NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Is the listview the same that I have shown above, or you have added the list view in a row or column

Comment: sir. how to convert postingDate '20191203' become '03/12/2019'.  I use intl packages, the printed current data is not the date from the database. DateTime now = DateTime.now(); String formattedDate = "${now.day}/${now.month}/${now.year}"; mutasiRek.content[i].postingDate = formattedDate.

Comment: if your date is of Datetime type the use the following method: `
  String getDate(DateTime dateIn) {
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy').format(dateIn);
    return formattedDate;
  }`

Comment: thanks. i have problem inputDate formatted. I want result convert Time("192624") to become "19:26:24". String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);  postResult.jam = formattedTime; is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First you could take a look at this resource:

https://bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-parse-json-string-array-to-object-list/#DartFlutter_parse_complex_JSON_into_Nested_Object

It will give you a better understanding of the parsing you're trying to do.

Then take a look at this another post:

https://pusher.com/tutorials/flutter-listviews

It will give an idea of how to handle ListViews properly

Comment: it's already done.  now, how to call array nested object in listview.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyModel> list=[];
var requestBody = jsonEncode({'accNumber': accNumber});
http.Response response = await http.post(apiURL, body: requestBody, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  print(data);
  for (Map<String,dynamic> m in data['content']){
      list.add(MyModel.fromJSON(m));
      //Replace above line with your model implemtation
   }
 );
}
```